# Edit a XML file from bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Want to edit XML file thru bash shell script.
I am stuck in finding a solution - Kindly share your suggestion if this can be resolved via bash shell script.

Input File(Will be stored in server):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
 <directories installDir="/fs0/">
  <directoriesInstance id="sharedDir" path=""/>
  <directoriesInstance id="loaderInput" path="/fs0/share/iad/input"/>
  <directoriesInstance id="loaderProcessing" path="/fs0/share/iad/processing"/>
  <directoriesInstance id="loaderError" path="/fs0/share/iad/error"/>
  <directoriesInstance id="loaderCompleted" path="/fs0/share/iad/completed"/>
 </directories>
  
  <applicationServerInstance id="app" serviceName="App Server" rmiPort="15001" jvmParameters="-Xmx3072m -Xms512m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:MaxPermSize=196m -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/fs0/clarity1/clarity/logs -Xloggc:/fs0/clarity1/clarity/logs/app_gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties" maxThreads="1000" programParameters="" distributed="false" runJobScheduler="false" useSSO="true" maxConcurrentJobs="10" runProcessEngine="false" messageTimeToLive="120" messageReceiverInterval="5" exceptionRunInterval="normal" maxXmlNodesLimit="150000"/>
  <applicationServer>
  <applicationServerInstance id="app" serviceName=" App Server" rmiPort="15001" jvmParameters="-Xmx3072m -Xms512m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:MaxPermSize=196m -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/fs0/clarity1/clarity/logs -Xloggc:/fs0/clarity1/clarity/logs/app_gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -Dcustom.properties=/fs0/clarity1/share/custom.properties" maxThreads="1000" programParameters="" distributed="false" runJobScheduler="false" useSSO="true" maxConcurrentJobs="10" runProcessEngine="false" messageTimeToLive="120" messageReceiverInterval="5" exceptionRunInterval="normal" maxXmlNodesLimit="150000"/>
 </applicationServer>

</properties>
```

In the above snippet I wanted to search for applicationServerInstance Tag and look if it has Dcustom.properties=/fs0/clarity1/share/custom.properties in jvmproperties tag - if it does not exists i wanted to add to the file and save the file.
All should be in bash shell script.

I want to add **-Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties** value to **jvmParameters** attribute In **applicationServerInstance** tag if it does not exists. In the above example it has this value,but incase if it does not exists I wanted to add this  **-Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties** value.

Say for Example I should add the **-Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties** value to **jvmParameters** attribute In **applicationServerInstance** tag to the below snippet.

```html
<applicationServerInstance id="app" serviceName=" App Server" rmiPort="15001" jvmParameters="-Xmx3072m -Xms512m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:MaxPermSize=196m -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/fs0/clarity1/clarity/logs -Xloggc:/fs0/clarity1/clarity/logs/app_gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC " maxThreads="1000" programParameters="" distributed="false" runJobScheduler="false" useSSO="true" maxConcurrentJobs="10" runProcessEngine="false" messageTimeToLive="120" messageReceiverInterval="5" exceptionRunInterval="normal" maxXmlNodesLimit="150000"/>
```

Comment: There's no `jvmproperties` *tag* , but the value is contained in `jvmParameters` *attribute* . Do you want to add the value, or replace an existing `custom.properties`?

Comment: I want to add **-Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties** value to **jvmParameters** attribute In **applicationServerInstance** tag if it does not exists. In the above example it has this value,but incase if it does not exists I wanted to add this  **-Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties** value.

Comment: You might take a look at xmlstarlet for command-line XML processing.

Comment: But what if `custom.properties` are present, but with a different value?

Comment: There is no possibility of having a different value in -Dcustom.propertie

Comment: We just want to check if there is -Dcustom.properties in jvmparmeters - if it is not present add the value to jvmparameters.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file, the first applicationServerInstance tag has jvmParameters with -Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties value. But in second applicationServerInstance tag, jvmParameter has -Dcustom.properties=/fs0/clarity1/share/custom.properties value instead of -Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties. In this case my code snippet add one more Dcustom.properties value.

So The second applicationServerInstance tag will be like this.

```
<applicationServerInstance id="app" serviceName=" App Server" rmiPort="15001" jvmParameters="-Xmx3072m -Xms512m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:MaxPermSize=196m -Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/fs0/clarity1/clarity/logs -Xloggc:/fs0/clarity1/clarity/logs/app_gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -Dcustom.properties=/fs0/clarity1/share/custom.properties -Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties" maxThreads="1000" programParameters="" distributed="false" runJobScheduler="false" useSSO="true" maxConcurrentJobs="10" runProcessEngine="false" messageTimeToLive="120" messageReceiverInterval="5" exceptionRunInterval="normal" maxXmlNodesLimit="150000"/>
```

**Bash Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file_name="/home/selvam/Scripts/test.xml"
for i in $(grep -nE "<applicationServerInstance.*jvmParameters" $file_name | cut -d ':' -f1)
do
    jvm_parameters=$(head -$i $file_name | tail -1 | awk -F '"' '{ for (c=1; c<=NF; c++) if ($c ~ /jvmParameters/) print $(c+1)}')
    echo $jvm_parameters | grep -q 'Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties'
    if ([ $? -ne 0 ]) then
        jvm_new_parameters=$(echo $jvm_parameters -Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties)
        sed -i "${i}s%jvmParameters=\"$jvm_parameters\"%jvmParameters=\"$jvm_new_parameters\"%" $file_name
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

**AWK**

```
awk -F"jvmParameters=" '{if((/applicationServerInstance/)&&($2!~/Dcustom.properties/)){sub("PrintHeapAtGC","PrintHeapAtGC -Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties")}print}' $inputfile
```

Would be another solution. Replace $inputfile with the name of the file you want to process.